# Find the fractional representation $p/q$...

Tags: fractions

Been trying to get some sort of solution for this for hours now, with no avail.

Find the fractional representation $p/q$, with $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$, of the rational number whose decimal representation is:

$22.521111...$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $x = 22.52111111\cdots,$ then $10x = 225.2111111\cdots$ subtracting one from the other gives you $9x = 202.69$ and $$x = \frac{202.69}{9} = \frac{20269}{900}. $$

Answer (score 2):

The repeating decimal is broken down to:
$$22.521111...=22.52+0.001111...=\frac{2252}{100}+\frac{1}{900}$$
Can you add up the fractions?

Comment: I thought it may be a little more involved than that? Why put all the p ∈ N,  q ∈ N, rational number information? Why not say convert this decimal to a fraction? Thanks though.

Comment: Yes sorry, the 1's are repeating.

Comment: 20269/900 - As above. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Liam, Because it is a "reading comprehension" style problem; to test the student's ability to interpret what the symbols and jargon mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general method:
$$22.5211111\dots=\frac{2252}{100}+\frac1{100}\times 0.11111\dots$$
Now $\enspace 0.11111=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{10^k}=\frac{\cfrac1{10}}{1-\cfrac1{10}}=\frac19$, so

$$22.5211111\dots=\frac{2252}{100}+\frac1{100}\frac19=\frac{9\cdot2252+1}{900}=\frac{20\,269}{900},$$
which is an irreducible fraction.

*High school version:*

Set $x=0.11111\dots$. Then $10x=1.11111\dots=1+0.11111\dots=1+x$, so $9x=1$.